# A call for sp_OA causes an error during execution inside a scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

We have a scalar function in the database that calls an assembly using `sp_OA methods`. The scalar function is called from a view. The SQL Server is Microsoft 2008 R2, a 32-bit installation. We have the same database installed on three different servers. On one of them the call to function fails with this message

> Msg 557, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 Only functions and some extended
>   stored procedures can be executed from within a function.

On the other two it works fine. Is there a setting we are missing on that one specific SQL Server? Or can it be something else? The internet is ambiguous about this error.

Thank you.

Comment: Holy nightmare. You have a view that calls a scalar function? Your scalar function in turn calls sp_OA methods? I see very strange behavior coming from something like this. What are you actually trying to do and why do want to call sp_OA methods from a view???

Comment: Agreed with @SeanLange - also (1) sp_OA has [a somewhat known variety of memory leaks](http://www.google.com/search?q=sp_oa+memory+leak) and is not the preferred method these days for most tasks (2) `32-bit` WHY WHY WHY? (3) While it's possible this may be due to compatibility level or [the `ole automation` sp_configure option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191188.aspx), I really think you should explore your actual requirements and solve this a better way. A view that calls a scalar function that tries to execute a stored procedure (esp. sp_OA) is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: I absolutely agree that the situation is less than optimal, or even more it stinks, and I expected the jeers and calls for "Why, God, why?". In the immortal words: "It is what it is.", and corporate budgets are stronger than any desire to make things better. The sp_OA calls old VB6 code, that can not be re-written or reproduced or re-factored in .net. SQL Server 2008 R2 64bit does not support OA calls, relying on assemblies. The scalar function just accepts one value and returns another through that sp_oa call.

Comment: It has been put in the scalar function format, for that reason specific, that it could be called from multiple SQL sources, including a view that is used for third party report engine. Aaron, thank you for the suggestion. I will take a look at sp_configure option. If it works on two out of three server instances must be something in the configuration, although the error is strange.

Comment: At least it's calling VB6 and not fortran or cobol

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the tips. The problem resolved itself rather unglamorously. It seems that an unhandled error in legacy code, through faulty data, was throwing the scalar function into a fit, causing the that particular error to show up.

Thank you.